# Product of locally Borel sets locally Borel

Tags: gn.general-topology, measure-theory, harmonic-analysis, borel-sets

Let $X$ be a locally compact Hausdorff space with a fixed Radon measure (= Borel measure that is finite on compact subsets, inner regular on open subsets and outer regular on Borel sets) $\mu$ . A subset $E\subseteq X$ is called locally Borel iff $E \cap A$ is a Borel subset of $X$ for every Borel subset $A$ of finite $\mu$-measure.

Suppose now that also $Y$ is a locally compact Hausdorff space and $F\subseteq Y$ is locally Borel with respect to a fixed Radon measure $\nu$ on $Y$.

Is it true that $E\times F$ is locally Borel in the product space $X\times Y$ with respect to the product Radon measure $\mu\times \nu$? I can prove this in the $\sigma$-compact or second countable case, but the general case is still unclear to me.

In other words, given $A\subseteq X \times Y$ with $(\mu\times \nu)(A) < \infty$, why is $A \cap (E\times F)$ a Borel subset? Or is this not true at all? I am mainly interested in the case where $\mu = \nu$ is Haar measure on a locally compact Hausdorff group.

Note that if $K\subseteq X \times Y$ is compact, then $K\subseteq K_1\times K_2$ where $K_1, K_2$ are the projections of $K$ onto its components. Hence,
$$K \cap (E\times F)= K\cap ((K_1\cap E)\times (K_2\cap F))$$
and $K_1\cap E, K_2\cap F$ are Borel. This does not depend on the Radon measure, so will not give a general proof.

Thanks in advance for your help and/or valuable suggestions!

Answer (score 1):

A somewhat disappointing answer: assuming that

1. $\mu\times\nu$ is Radon and outer regular,
2. you complete the measure space $(X \times Y, \mathcal{B}(X\times Y), \mu\times \nu)$, i.e. add the sets of $\mu\times\nu$-measure zero to the Borel sigma-algebra,

then the product of any locally Borel sets is locally Borel, see proof below. Point 2 seems unavoidable but not very costly.

I am not sure how to prove or disprove point 1 in general. It seems to be true at least when $\mu$ and $\nu$ are $\sigma$-finite, see [this thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1370814/langs-treatment-of-product-of-radon-measures) and the book cited within. Maybe you can use the representation of Radon measures as elements of the dual of the space of continuous functions with compact supports; see point 6.5 of *[Godfrey, M. C., & Sion, M. (1969). On product of Radon measures. Canadian Mathematical Bulletin, 12(4), 427-444]* (and the reference to Bourbaki therein for completeness) together with the [Riesz-Markov-Kakutani representation theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz%E2%80%93Markov%E2%80%93Kakutani_representation_theorem#The_representation_theorem_for_positive_linear_functionals_on_Cc(X)).

**Proof.** Let $C \subset X\times Y$ Borel with finite measure. By point 1, for every $\epsilon>0$ there exists $\tilde O \subset O \supset C$ with $O$ open and $\tilde O$ $\sigma$-compact such that
$$ \mu\times\nu(\tilde O) = \mu\times\nu(O) \leq \epsilon + \mu\times\nu(C).$$
Using similar arguments as in your answer, $\tilde O \cap (E\times F)$ is Borel, thus (using the completion in point 2) so is $O \cap (E\times F)$, and finally so is $C\cap(E\times F)$. $\square$

Answer (score 0):

In case that $G:=X=Y$ is a locally compact group and $\lambda:=\mu= \nu$ Haar measure, the answer is positive.

Let $A\subseteq G \times G$ be a Borel set with $(\lambda\times \lambda)(A)<\infty$. Then there exist $\sigma$-compact subsets $K,L\subseteq G$ with $A\subseteq K\times L$. Therefore,
$$A\cap (E\times F)= A \cap (K\times L)\cap (E\times F) = A\cap [(K\cap E)\times (L\cap F)]$$
which is Borel since $K\cap E$ is Borel and $L\cap F$ is Borel.