# Is the product of two outer regular Radon measures outer regular?

Tags: gn.general-topology, measure-theory

Everything is nice on second countable spaces: the product of two outer regular Radon measure is still an outer regular Radon measure. But what happens without the assumption of second countability?

Checking that the product measure is finite on all compact sets is easy: the projections are continuous, so any compact set of the product is contained in the product of two compact sets, thus has finite measure.

**But what about inner regularity? Outer regularity?**

The motivation comes from [this post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/446786/product-of-locally-borel-sets-locally-borel/447409#447409) by @Andromeda, where my answer requires $\mu\times\nu$ to be an outer regular Radon measure.

### Radon measures

Working in the fullest generality, let $X, Y$ be locally compact Hausdorff topological spaces. Most importantly, **I do not assume that they are second countable.** There are two definitions of Radon measures:

**Definition 1: a Borel measure $\mu$ on $X$ is Radon if**

1. **for every compact $K\subset X$, $\mu(K)<\infty$**
2. **(inner regularity) for every open set $O$, $\mu(O) = \sup \mu(K)$, where the supremum is over all compact sets $K\subset O$.**

**Definition 2: a Radon measure is a positive linear functional on the space $C_c(X)$ of continuous functions from $X$ to $\mathbb R$ with compact support, equipped with the topology induced by the $(\|\cdot\|_{\infty,K} : K \text{compact})$.**

The two definitions are equivalent thanks to the [Riesz–Markov–Kakutani representation theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz%E2%80%93Markov%E2%80%93Kakutani_representation_theorem#The_representation_theorem_for_positive_linear_functionals_on_Cc(X)).
In many cases, a Radon measure also satisfies

3. (outer regularity) for every Borel set $A$, $\mu(A) = \inf \mu(O)$, where the infimum is over all open sets $O\supset A$.

I thought at first (and so did @Andromeda in the post I linked) that outer regularity was an axiom of a Radon measure.
It is however [not true](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radon_measure#Moderated_Radon_measures); see the example of a non-moderated measure, which cannot be outer regular – in such examples, it is essentially impossible for the measure to be inner and outer regular at the same time.

### Product of measures

The topological space $X\times Y$ equipped with the product topology can be equipped with the Borel sigma-algebra $\mathcal B$, or by the product sigma-algebra $\mathcal P$. Obviously $\mathcal B \supset \mathcal P$, and both agree when $X$ and $Y$ are second countable, but [might disagree otherwise](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/39882/product-of-borel-sigma-algebras).

Let $\mu,\nu$ be Radon measures on $X$ and $Y$ respectively. The product measure $\mu\times\nu$ can be defined in several ways. I am only interested in defining it on $\mathcal B$.

1. by [Carathéodory’s extension theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carath%C3%A9odory%27s_extension_theorem), by extending the premeasure $A\times B \mapsto \mu(A)\nu(B)$ on the algebra of sets $\{(A,B) : A \text{ measurable in } X,B \text{ measurable in } Y\}$ into an outer measure, for which we then find the [$\sigma$-algebra of sets that are measurable for this outer measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carath%C3%A9odory%27s_criterion).
2. by extending the positive linear functional on the subset of $C_c(X\times Y)$ of all functions $f\otimes g: (x,y) \mapsto f(x)g(y)$ with $f\in C_c(X)$ and $g\in C_c(Y)$:
   $$ L : f\otimes g \mapsto \left(\int f d\mu\right) \left( \int g d\nu\right) $$
   into a positive linear functional of $C_c(X\times Y)$, which we then identify to a Radon measure on $\mathcal B$ by definition 2.

Both definitions are equivalent when the sets are second countable.

The second approach is the one chosen by Bourbaki, Éléments de Mathématiques, livre VI: Intégration, chap. I-IV *(I am in the process of reading it, so I might have missed some subtleties there.)*
The second one [seems to have better properties](https://www.cambridge.org/core/services/aop-cambridge-core/content/view/0A102C2034167629D2F8C92F36F39BF2/S0008439500053856a.pdf/on-product-of-radon-measures.pdf), since in general it is not always easy to prove that every set in $\mathcal B$ is measurable. [See also](https://msp.org/pjm/1972/42-3/p03.xhtml). In particular, the inner regularity is immediate.

### Questions

***Question:** if $\mu$ and $\nu$ are outer regular, is $\mu\times\nu$ outer regular? (Looking for counter-example and/or conditions under which this does or does not hold.)*

***Bonus question:** what changes when completing one or several of the Borel $\sigma$-algebra on $X$, resp. $Y$, resp. $X\times Y$?*